# Working on two different Firebase realtime databases using one Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to develop an app where I would be able to save info in two different Firebase realtime databases. Currently, my app is connected to one database (and works good). I used the following code:

```
    private DatabaseReference RootRef;

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("******") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("******") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("********") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary");
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
    FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
    RootRef = secondaryDatabase.getReference();
    RootRef.child("Groups").child("test").setValue("").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Group created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

(Of course I filled the *** with the new project's data)

But when I try to use the second database, it seems like nothing happens in it. For every action I do, it affects only the first database. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the device log say?

Comment: "it seems like nothing happens in it" That's a bit unclear/non-actionable. What happens when you use `app` to access the database? Did you check if `app` contains the correct configuration data/database URL?

Comment: I will be able to answer you only in a few hours. thanks anyway

Comment: Have you sued both references separately and it didn't work? Is your `onComplete` even triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
// Get the default database instance for an app
DatabaseReference primary = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference();

// Get a secondary database instance by URL
DatabaseReference secondary = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com")
        .getReference();
```

Kotlin

```
// Get the default database instance for an app
val primary = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

// Get a secondary database instance by URL
val secondary = FirebaseDatabase
    .getInstance("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com").reference
```

Comment: I will try this in a few hours and update you.
Thanks for the quick answer!